# Chrome never reads key NativeMessagingHosts to run native messaging

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that I'm developing.  Using process monitor, I'm filtering on NativeMessagingHosts in the path and it never gets hit on the registry.  Here is my REG file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.app.native.messaging.ChromeMessageRepeater]
@="C:\\Prototypes\\Plugins\\DG2\\com.app.native.messaging.ChromeMessageRepeater.json"
```

Now, here is the JSON for the plugin manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "--------- 2.0",
  "description": "",
  "version": "2.0",
  "content_scripts" :[
    {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "run_at": "document_idle",
        "js": ["jquery-1.12.2.min.js", "dg2.js"]
    }  
  ],
  "background": {
    "page": "back.html",
    "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": [ "nativeMessaging", "alarms", "tabs", "activeTab", "*://*/*"]
}
```

here is the json for the native messaging app

```
{
  "name": "com.app.native.messaging.ChromeMessageRepeater",
  "description": "",
  "path": "ChromeMessageRepeater.exe",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://lpldkcbggjamnjbndpddgoikgeabfapb/"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging"
  ]
}
```

Any idea why the registry key is never read?  When trying to use the plugin, the Port is never opened if I use `chrome.runtime.connectNative` nor if I used `chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage`

EDIT:

```
function postMessage2(url, dom) {
    var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative("com.app.native.messaging.ChromeMessageRepeater");
    if(typeof chrome.runtime.lastError !== 'undefined') console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        console.log("Received" + msg);
    });
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
        console.log("Disconnected");
    });

    try {
        port.postMessage({ text: url + ';' + dom });
    }
    catch(ex) { 
        console.error(ex); 
    }
};

function postMessage(url, dom) {
    chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage("com.app.native.messaging.ChromeMessageRepeater", { text: url + ';' + dom });
    if(typeof chrome.runtime.lastError !== 'undefined') {
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    }
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(request.type === "native"){
            postMessage2(request.url, request.dom);
            sendResponse({ result: true });
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Have you already tried to debug the issue using https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-debugging ?

Comment: Just enabled debugging and found nothing at all on the console when I run do anything other than a few ssl errors.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting when you try `connectNative` or `sendNativeMessage`?

Comment: That's the thing.  I never get an error.  Likewise, my app never gets called, either.

Comment: Can you add the relevant code for the connectNative/sendNativeMessage call in the question?

Comment: I've added the code.

Comment: Are you sure that you're calling `connectNative` / `sendNativeMessage`? So if you put a `console.log` before the call, you see a message in the console, right? The location of the `chrome.runtime.lastMessage` check is incorrect. In `sendNativeMessage`, you have to put it in the callback. In `connectNative`, it must be in the `onDiscconect` listener.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107347/discussion-between-payton-byrd-and-rob-w).